How can I grab a window with widgets and title bar?
I am trying to save a snapshot of a QMainWindow with widgets and title bar.
This is how I tried:
from time import sleep

from PySide6.QtCore import QRect
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QStyle

application = QApplication()
extra_top = application.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PixelMetric.PM_TitleBarHeight)

button = QPushButton("Hello, world!")

w = QMainWindow()
w.setCentralWidget(button)
w.show()

# Try a bunch of things
w.update()
w.repaint()
w.show()
sleep(0.1)
w.update()
w.repaint()
w.show()
sleep(0.1)

# This snapshot shows the button, but not the title bar
w.grab(
    QRect(
        0,
        -extra_top,
        w.width(),
        w.height() + extra_top,
    )
).save("grabWidget.png")

# This snapshot shows the title bar, but not the button
w.screen().grabWindow(
    w.winId(),
    x=0,
    y=-extra_top,
    w=w.width(),
    h=w.height() + extra_top,
).save("grabWindow.png")

First snapshot:

Second snapshot:

How do I get the best of both?

You're not allowing any time for the window to be fully rendered. Put the screen().grabWindow code in a slot and call it via a single-shot timer with a short delay (about 100 ms should be enough). You will also need to start the event-loop for this to work.

@ekhumoro thanks, that seems to be working. What is QTimer doing that sleep is not?

Sleep will block the event-loop and freeze the GUI. A timer will post an event and any connected slots will be called asynchronously.

It's weird, though, that QWidget.grab() receives the full content without any tricks. Maybe because that's an internal routine that (re-)renders offscreen, while grabWindow() gets it from the OS's screen content.

It's not weird at all. The sleep will just block execution of the script, then resume as normal. It makes no difference at all in your original script. The timer is required to allow time for a frame to be created for the window and place it on the screen. Exactly how and when this happens depends on the OS, and is entirely outside of Qt's control. This is why a timer and event-loop are required - Qt needs to release control and wait for all the relevant system events to take place before it resumes execution. Using sleep inside the main thread would stop that happening.

PS: your current script does not calculate the decorated window rect correctly. It should instead do x=w.frameGeometry().x() - w.geometry().x(),  y=w.frameGeometry().y() - w.geometry().y(), w=w.frameGeometry().width(),  h=w.frameGeometry().height().

@ekhumoro yes, I received the same comment over at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78717054 :) the result of the computations is the same, but I will use frameGeometry from now on.
