Why is the title bar captured incorrectly after changing the width of a window?
I felt this was related to How can I grab a window with widgets and title bar?, but it seems to have a different solution.
When capturing a (window with a) title bar, I get unexpected results after resizing.
from PySide6.QtCore import QTimer
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

application = QApplication()
window = QMainWindow()
window.show()
screen = window.screen()


def save_titlebar(filename: str) -> None:
    window.screen().grabWindow(
        window.winId(),
        x=window.frameGeometry().x() - window.geometry().x(),
        y=window.frameGeometry().y() - window.geometry().y(),
        w=window.frameGeometry().width(),
        h=window.frameGeometry().height() - window.geometry().height(),
    ).save(filename)


def set_width_and_save(width: int) -> None:
    window.setFixedWidth(width)
    QTimer.singleShot(500, lambda: save_titlebar(f"titlebar{width}.png"))


QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: set_width_and_save(400))
QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: set_width_and_save(500))
QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: set_width_and_save(300))
QTimer.singleShot(4000, window.close)
application.exec()

titlebar400.png:

titlebar500.png:

titlebar300.png:

How can I make sure the title bar is updated before the snapshot?

Similarly to your previous question, you don't leave enough time to the OS and toolkit to handle events. Use QTimer.singleShot. Note that, while it may coincidentally give a consistent result, you should not rely on the pixel metric of PM_TitleBarHeight, because that value is not actually used to draw windows decorations (that's the OS responsibility, Qt has absolutely no role in that). You should always use frameGeometry().

@musicamante 500ms should be enough, I guess - but that does not help.

That shouldn't happen. Do you see the window being actually resized when you run the script above? Just to be sure, is the above the result of that very script, right? You're not trying to use some subclass or customized window, are you? If you're not, then what OS and version? What specific PySide and Qt version? Also, try to replace window.winId() with 0.

@musicamante "Do you see the window being actually resized when you run the script above?" yes. "the result of that very script?" yes. "trying to use some subclass or customized window" no. Windows 11 23H2, PySide6 6.7.2 (not sure which Qt version). With windows.winId() replaced by 0, screenshots are correct size (as before) but all black.

I filed https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2811.

It works fine for me on Linux, so it seems like a platform-specific issue. You could try adding QApplication.processEvents() after setting the window width and/or before grabbing the screenshot.

@bers It's quite unlikely that this is a PySide bug, and it most certainly is a Qt one if confirmed (so, you should really check the Qt version, "not sure which" isn't acceptable, and report it as a QTBUG, not PYSIDE).

@musicamante I am >99% sure PySide6 version always equals the Qt version, except in cases where PySide6 is re-released such as in 6.6.3.1. Anyway. The reason I filed as PYSIDE and not QTBUG is that QTBUG bug requires me to provide a reproducible code example in C++, which I do not use (for Qt). I had this thing in the past where PYSIDE would say "we can reproduce but it's not us" (as they just did), and QTBUG would say "we don't know if it's us until we have a C++ example". But let me try again... https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-127021

@bers Posting in PYSIDE because you cannot write in C++ is inappropriate in any case for a bug that is evidently not inherent to PySide, since that category is intended for bugs that are exclusive to issues of the binding. QTBUG may ask for C++ examples under certain circumstances, but that's not a strict nor explicit requirement for filing reports (especially if the bug is well reported): I filed many QTBUGs with Python code (some even with PyQt), I never received complaints and they have always been accepted. Note: you should attach images to the report, not link them externally.

@musicamante good for you. I experienced https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-115635

@bers I'll look into it, but consider that the very fact that you're using QTest may change things, especially considering that some events (notably including those related to what you used: keyboard shortcuts, access to view/selection model and even QAbstractScrollArea/focus related stuff) do need a running event loop, which you don't have in neither examples. This, and the fact that the Python bindings may create further unexpected issues, may require a proper C++ example, at least for comparison. Those are quite different bugs, and, as you see, it seems your latest one wasn't discarded.
